# URL Routing - error image (Asp.net web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, routes

I am writing a web page to show image.  I have used the asp.net web forms URL routing to navigate to this page.
map web:

```
webform1.aspx with master page: site.Master.
'demo.jpg' in folder Images.
demo.jpg is banner of site.Master
2 link in site.Master:
.../home
.../home/gp
```

url:

```
http://localhost:42370/webform1.aspx
```

rewriter:

```
http://localhost:42370/home
```

Link image:

```
http://localhost:42370/Images/demo.jpg
```

but when click to url

```
http://localhost:42370/home/gp
```

image error and link image:

```
http://localhost:42370/home/gp/Images/demo.jpg
```

When click 'home' again:

```
http://localhost:42370/home/home
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

PS: i used:

```
routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
```

or

```
routes.Add(new Route("*\.jpg", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

but it not work
plz, help me :(
routing here:

```
void RegisterRouter(RouteCollection r)
{
    r.MapPageRoute("", "home", "~/webform1.aspx");
    r.MapPageRoute("", "home/{grap}", "~/webform1.aspx");
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    RegisterRouter(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: We need your entire routing setup to diagnose appropriately, likely you have it in the wrong order. Routes are processed top-down.

Comment: thank EBrow, it here:
r.MapPageRoute("", "home", "~/webform1.aspx");
r.MapPageRoute("", "home/{grap}", "~/webform1.aspx");
plz help me

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: What exactly is the error? You don't add that ignore to your routing at all either.

Comment: i was try add ignore, but it not work. file 'demo.jpg' till error

Comment: somebody help me :(((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
runat="server"
```

as an attribute for the tag, like:

```
<a href="~/Images/demo.jpg" runat="server">...</a>
```